# Retrofit headers NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, header, retrofit

I have problem with retrofit and custom RequestInterceptor. I am trying to add header with content-type to every request i make, so i made custom RequestInterceptor like this:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder().
setEndpoint(Configuration.BASE_ENDPOINT).
setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                }
            }).
build();
```

but **`NullPointerException`** is thrown when i try to call some API.

I traced down the issue to RequestBuilder class to this line:

```
headers.add(new Header("Content-Type", contentTypeHeader));
```

**Error :**

```
 on line 344 : ArrayList headers is null.
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong ? I used this exact code in other project and it was working just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Have you initialized `headers` as `List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();`

Comment: Well, because RequestBuilder is not my class but retrofit class, I cannot initialize anything.

Comment: Not sure what's happening but from the looks of it you might not be using the latest version (1.6.1).  Are you?

Comment: Well, I am using the newest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in Retrofit.  The headers list in RequestBuilder class is lazily initialized and in the case where you add the `"Content-Type"` header ONLY through a `RequestInterceptor` the headers list isn't initialized.  This issue disappear as soon as you add an extra header different than `"Content-Type"`.  `"Content-Type"` header is treated differently in the code and if it's the only header provided this issue occurs.

If `"Content-Type"` is the only header you want to intercept then to get around this issue instead I would simply @annotate your interface with the `@Headers("Content-type: application/json")` and you'll be able to get around it.

```
@Headers("Content-type: application/json")
@GET("/some_resource_path")
Response getData();
```

I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/557) for it.